# What's the best socket.io server for use with Django - gevent or tornadio2?

Tags: django, socket.io, tornado, gevent

I'm working on a WebApp using backbone.js and socket.io on the client side, and Django on the server side. I'd like to do "push" from the server when data changes (just like in a chat app). I came across two implementation of socket.io in Python with a Django integration that looked promising:

- [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) which is based on gevent and gevent-socketio
- Tornado-based integrations that use [torandio2](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) such as [tornadio-with-django](https://github.com/felixleong/tornadio-with-django) and [django-tornadio](https://github.com/k1000/django-tornadio)

Both gevent and tornado have [very good performance](http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python), so I'm not interested in other async connection frameworks. The only other requirement is the use of SSL for the connection - no plain text transmission.

So between these two approached, which would be the easiest to implement? Is there a good subscription-based framework for tornadio2 similar to how django-socketio does it for gevent?

Another option I came across is [django-serverpush](https://github.com/hamax/django-serverpush), which is also based on TornadIO2. It better integrates with Django than the other TornadIO2 apps, but the implementation still needs some improvement before it becomes production-ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, django-socketio still hasn't been fully upgraded to work with the latest socket.io.

Tornado/TornadIO2 on the other hand are well maintained, and with a few custom extensions I was able to get them up and running very nicely. After I launch my product, I'm hoping to spend some time to open-source my modifications. Until then, I'd be happy to answer any questions on how to get this running.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I'd say they're pretty similar. This is more of an opinion. For performance I think gevent has more performance based on what I've read, but you should do your own tests to find out which has highest performance.

Comment: From my research their performance is comparable, so that wouldn't be a factor. I was more concerned with how tightly they integrate with Django, easier to work with, and better maintained.

Comment: I'd go with Django-SocketIO if I were you.